# XSD Conditional Child Element based on Attribute

Tags: xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I have a xml which can have 2 types of nodes as mentioned below:

Type 1:

```
<node attr1="false" attr2="attr2">
   <node attr1="true" attr2="attr2" attr3="attr3" attr4=""></node>
</node>

<node attr1="false" attr2="attr2">
 <node attr1="false" attr2="attr2">
  <node attr1="true" attr2="attr2" attr3="attr3" attr4="">
 </node>
 </node>
 <node attr1="true" attr2="attr2" attr3="attr3" attr4=""></node>
```

Type 2:

```
<node attr1="true" attr2="attr2" attr3="attr3" attr4=""></node>
```

If attr1 value is false, then it'll have sub nodes, and no attr3, attr4 will be there

If attr1 value is true, then it'll not have any sub nodes, and attr3, attr4 will be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with asserts in XSD 1.1, but I can't see a way to do it in XSD 1.0

[image: Graphical representation of XSD schema using Liquid XML Studio]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition 15.0.0.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="node">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="attr1" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="attr2" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="attr3" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="attr4" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:assert test="string(@attr1) = ('false', '0') or boolean(@attr3)" />
            <xs:assert test="string(@attr1) = ('false', '0') or boolean(@attr4)" />
            <xs:assert test="string(@attr1) = ('true', '1') or not(boolean(@attr3))" />
            <xs:assert test="string(@attr1) = ('true', '1') or not(boolean(@attr4))" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```